# Change Attribute of Object Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question title is very complicated to understand, but I need help to solve this problem. I have an element, and when I click it, it shows a new window webpage. I don't know why. So I've tried to override it with [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) API from jQuery, but it's didn't worked. I've tried to use Chrome dev tools to detect event handler and found it.

[image: Object]

I think this `clickValue` make this action. But, I can't remove this js file. How can I change this `clickValue` string value or prevent open new web page window when I click my element.

If my question title is hardly to understand. Please let me know to edit it. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @gcampbell, I want to change clickValue string or some other solution to remove this action when I click my element. Because I think this make, I can't override my event handler when to click it.

Comment: @PhamMinhTan, so you  have an element that opens a new window when clicked, so want to prevent it. though not an elegant solution but $(element).off('click') should work.

Comment: I've tried this solution but it's didn't work. I mention this in my question above

Comment: @PhamMinhTan try setting the onclick property like so: `$(element).onclick = null`

Comment: No effect with it @HansStrausl :(

Comment: @PhamMinhTan can you link to the website in question? That would make this much easier.

Comment: Sorry @HansStrausl, this is private web page in LAN.

Comment: @PhamMinhTan okay maybe try this: `$(element).onclick = function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;}`